# How to give several variable to the same entity filter in easyadmin3

Tags: filter, symfony5, easyadmin3

I use the filters from easyadmin3.It work well but i need to be able to send several variables to the same entity filter.

Here is the crudControllerpart :

```
 public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
          AssociationField::new('commande','Commande'),
          DateField::new('startingDate','Date Début')->hideonIndex(),
          TextField::new('getStartingDateWeek','Date Début')->hideOnForm(),
          DateField::new('endingDate','Date Fin'),
          AssociationField::new('autoclave','Autoclave'),
          AssociationField::new('liquide','Liquide'),
          AssociationField::new('rehausse','Rehausse'),
          NumberField::new('charge')->hideOnForm(),
          NumberField::new('chargeActuelle','Charge Actuelle')->hideOnForm(),
          NumberField::new('quantityReserved','Qte réservée'),
          TextField::new('fillingRate','Qte Commande')->hideOnForm(),
          BooleanField::new('fondDouble','Double fond'),
          BooleanField::new('quadrupleFond','Quadruple fond'),
        ];
    }
```

and here the filter

> ```
>   public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
>     {
>       return $filters
>         ->add(EntityFilter::new('autoclave'))
>         ->add('startingDate')
>         ->add('charge')
>         ->add('commande')
>         ;
>     }
> ```

I want to give several variable from autoclave's entity to the filter, to be able to see for exemple all autoclave A AND B, not only A or only B.
I know i could probably use a custom filter, but there isnt a native option for this ? The documentation isnt quite accurate.

Comment: What i'm seeking for it something like ->setFormTypeOptions([
          'multiple' => true,
      ])   but usable with the filter.

Comment: ->add(EntityFilter::new('autoclave')->setFormTypeOptions([ 'multiple' => true, ]) was indeed the solution but i just didnt understood i had to ctrl+clic to select several choice. I was expecting something more visual ^^.